# Is there a way to get the Dex Loader in Android to allow multiple of a class?

Tags: java, android

I get the "Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define xxx" error when I have an android project that uses a library project and they both generate a class with the same name in the apt_generated folder.  The class is exactly the same name and contents in both projects but since there are multiple of it I get an error when trying to deploy.  Is there a flag or anything that can be set which will always use the first class and ignore any others with the same name?

Comment: AFAIK, no. Move the class in question into another project, so both library projects can refer to the same implementation, rather than each having their own. Or, refactor one implementation into a new package.

Answer (score 3):

One options is to exclude the library project from the build in one of the projects.

Library project dependencies are stored in the `Android Private Libraries` classpath container in Eclipse/ADT.

In the latest ADT (and probably in older versions to), you can opt to not export this classpath container.

Imagine the scenario were you have a project depending on

- the Google Play Services Library.
- android-maps-utils (A google maps extension library project that also depends on Google Play Services)

In this case you will run into the following error at package/deploy time :

```
Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/R$attr;
Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/R$attr;
```

If you configure the android-maps-utils project to not export the `Android Private Libraries` by unchecking the highlighted container in the `Order and Export1 view of the Java Build path, the Dex error will go away.

[image]