# NoClassDefFoundError and other errors when referncing Google Maps Android API Utility

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm developing and android application using Google Maps.
Everything was fine until I used Google Maps Android API Utility.

I followed the instructions in

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/setup

to install and use the library in my application, but when i try to launch it I get a `NoClassDefFoundError`at runtime

Then I followed the instructions in

[couldn't run Google Maps Android API Utility Demo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22840952/couldnt-run-google-maps-android-api-utility-demo)

but now the application doesn't start at all, when I try to launch it I get a prompt with the following message

"Your project contains errors, please fix them before running your application"

and on the log I have

```
Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/R$attr;
Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/R$attr;
```

what should I do to solve this issue? Thanks

Comment: This is something to do with Java Build Path -> Order and Export tab. Try unselecting all the dependencies from Project-> Properties-> Java Build Path-> Order and Export and clean build your project.

Comment: Just to add to the comment of @rizzz86, the only answer in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17032157/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-dex-loader-in-android-to-allow-multiple-of-a-class) post solves the exact same error you are having. However, I am not sure if it will solve the NoClassDefFoundError that you had. Can you paste the logs that print this error if they reoccur?